# Is this expression correct?

Tags: expressions

Is it right in English to say:

> It is nice a day.

instead of

> It is a nice day.

Is any sentence of this form correct?

Comment: **It is nice today.** is a little more colloquial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second, "it is a nice day" is correct because you would put the adjective (nice) right next to the noun (day).

The first, "it is nice a day" is wrong because the article (a) cannot be inserted in between.

Comment: I know the second is right, so that is not helpful

Comment: @kalkanistovinko The answer is correct though. "it is nice a day" is incorrect English. Google seems to back me up on this one having a whole 9 results...all of which are improper English usages anyway.

Comment: @NathanC: I edited my answer to add the second paragraph after the comment was made. I had initially tried to imply that the first was wrong by highlighting the feature of the second that was necessary to its being correct, but I really should have been more explicit in the first place.

Comment: Thanks and excuse me, but I thought you were uncertain about the first and therefore ignored it.